If the minimal polynomials of endomorphisms $A$ and $B$ split, does the minimal polynomial of $AB$ also split?
So if the minimal polynomials of endomorphisms $A$ and $B$, of some finite-dimensional vector space (not sure it's important) split, does the minimal polynomial of $AB$ also split?
I'm not sure how to go about this, but I know this would be equivalent to asking whether the product of two triangulable endomorphisms is again triangulable. The problem in this case being that they might be triangulable with respect to different bases.

No, see for instance $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\ 0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ as endomorphisms of $\Bbb R^2$.

I'm not sure that works. The product is the map sending $e_1$ to $-e_2$ and sending $e_2$ to $-e_1$. But choosing for example the basis $v_1 = e_1 + e_2$ and $v_2 = e_1$, this map is triangulable. Am I missing something?

$e_1$ to $e_2$.

Ah, didn't see the edit. Yeah, that seems to work. Thanks!
